# Loop though a list of hostnames to see if using ssh on them is successful

Tags: expect

I have a task which has been giving me headaches quite a while. Basically, I'm given a list of hostnames alongside their usernames and passwords (each hostname has a username and a password). I am to write a script so that I can automatically ssh from the list of login details provided. I am using an expect script to do it. This is what I've come up with so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# Values to retrieve elements from the list based on the index
set x 0
set y 0

set HSTNMLIST [list 192.168.6.99 192.168.0.32 192.168.3.77]
set USRNMLIST [list user1 user2 user3]
set PSSWRDLIST [list asfsa bvgtrnh bdfbdfg]

foreach n $HSTNMLIST {
    spawn ssh $USRNMLIST[$x]@$n 
    expect "password"
    send "$PSSWRDLIST[$y]\r" 
    if { expect "continue connecting" } {
        send "No\r"
        incr $x
    } else {
        send "No\r"
        expect "Permission denied"
        send "No\r"
        incr $y
    }
}
interact
```

Right now I'm stuck at figuring out how retrieve an element based on the indexes in the loop function. Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: ugh! expect Tcl is such a pain.  I found that using python's pexpect / pxssh is SO MUCH easier if you know python. https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html

Comment: Greetings. I see a **bash** tag. Is there a bash component to your question? Also, are you just going to assume that host keys are correct, or is there some setup stage where you might (1) verify host keys and (2) set up key-based authentication instead of having to use passwords? Lastly, what are you planning to DO with your ssh connection? Are you just verifying that you *can* authenticate, or is there a missing command in there?

Comment: Apologies. I thought expect and bash were the same thing. As for the task, the idea is to see if a hostname with it's provided username and password can successfully connect to ssh and produce the results in a .txt file. All the hostnames are unverified, so my plan is just to see if it the hostname, username and password manages to reach the prompt where the terminal asks if you would like to continue connecting, to which I would say 'no' and continue through the list

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
for {set idx 0} {$idx < [llength $HSTNMLIST]} {incr i} {
    set host [lindex $HSTNMLIST $idx]
    set user [lindex $USRNMLIST $idx]
    set pswd [lindex $PSSWRDLIST $idx]

    spawn ssh $user@$host
    ...
    send "$pswd\r"
```

Or are you wanting to try all combinations of username/password for each host?